# Merging Database schema

Tags: database-design

We are having 3 different projects all having there own database [Oracle] schema, which is leading to issues as we always have to give grants for one schema to access tables of other schema.
 So our plan is to create a single schema instead of 3 schemas but then issues comes with data which is already present in those 3 schema. We dont want to copy over the data as its huge and our application can point only to one schema not to both.

Is there a way that this can be achieved taking care of above concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Database merging is a fun activity, I'm working on a bit of that myself at the moment.

Since you don't want to actually copy everything into one schema a good solution may be to make views which pull from all three, and use these in your application instead of the current tables it's using.